# Verified domain not appearing in drop down to link a domain to an Azure Communication Service

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

I have an Azure Communication Service, an Email Service and a verified domain.  Attempting to connect the domain to the Communication Service doesn't include my verified domain in the selectable domains.

When viewing the Communication Service | Domains, there are no connected domains so I click Connect A Domain.  In the dropdowns I can select the Subscription, the Resource Group and the Email Service, but there are no domains in the Verified Domain dropdown.  I expected to see my (only) verified domain in the dropdown.

Viewing the Email Communication Service | Provision Domains, it definitely has a custom domain that has been verified (shows a green checkmark and says Verified).

What would prevent this verified domain from appearing in the dropdown and being selectable/connectable?

Comment: I understand you are unable to see your verified domain in the dropdown list.
There might be a delay in propagating the verified domain information to Azure Communication Service (ACS). If the issue still persists, to isolate the issue, 
1. Ensure that the verified domain is not associated with the same subscription, resource group, or email service as your ACS.
2. Ensure that the verified domain is not already connected to another ACS resource. 

Have you completed all the steps? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/add-custom-verified-domains

Answer (score 0):

@user22346892, Following-up from my comments. Based on the issue description, I understand you are unable to see your verified domain in the dropdown list.

There might be a delay in propagating the verified domain information to Azure Communication Service (ACS).

If the issue still persists, to isolate the issue:

1. Ensure that the verified domain is not associated with the same
   subscription, resource group, or email service as your ACS.
2. Ensure that the verified domain is not already connected to another ACS resource.

Have you completed all the steps? [Quickstart: How to add custom verified domains to Email Communication Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/add-custom-verified-domains).